# How to swap STDIO.H library functions with strictly system calls?

Tags: c, linux

A simple program that takes an input file specified at the terminal, and alters the text to be reversed. How can the `<stdio.h>` functions be converted to only linux system calls? (I assume using only libraries like `<unistd.h>`)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* concat(const char *str1, const char *str2)
{
    char *answer = malloc(strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 1);
    strcpy(answer, str1);
    strcat(answer, str2);
    return answer;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    FILE * fp;
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (fp == NULL){
        perror("\nError ");
        exit(1);
    }

    char *rev1 = "rev ";
    char *rev2 = {argv[1]};
    char *rev3 = concat(rev1,rev2);

    system(rev3);

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for any help. Company only wants me to use system calls for some reason, this internship is not going great!

Comment: The request doesn't make no sense. For example, there's no `printf` system call, though calling `printf` will eventually result in system calls (such as `write`).  That makes `printf` C code that makes system calls, which is exactly what you asked for. Same goes for the rest of stdio. The few function that seem to have a direct system call equivalent (e.g. `fopen` and `fclose`) are needed to support the functions that don't. Maybe they want unbuffered I/O? Please clarify.

Comment: I'm reasonably sure unistd.h is implemented by glibc anyway, so you're still using the C library. Do they expect you to make the interrupt calls from your own code? Why? Can you ask them more specifically what they want, and ideally an example too.

Comment: *The request makes no sense.

Comment: @ikegami I apologize, I'm allowed to use `printf` for debugging and `perror`, but nothing else.  For example, how would I replace all of the file functions using write and read?

Comment: Again, all the stdio functions already use `write` and `read`. So according to you, you should be able to use them. If you don't want to, fine, but it's unclear what you want from us.

Comment: @ikegami I understand that it utilizes the `write` and `read`, I just need to show that I can only use those functions. Would you be able to swap the necessary functions with their more primitive counterparts?

Comment: What do you mean by swap? Replace the word `fprintf` with `write`? No, they have different arguments. Use a function that takes the same arguments as `fprintf` and calls `write`? You can do that. The function is called `fprintf`.

Comment: If `write` is a screw driver and `fprintf` is a power drill, you are asking "I can't use a power drill, but I want to unscrew screws using a powered screw driver"

Comment: Can you use `sprintf` for formatting? If so, then `sprintf`` to a buffer and `write` the buffer.

Comment: @Avi Berger, That's no diffferent than an unbuffered `printf`/`fprintf`. I've already suggested this might be what they want.

Comment: Have you asked for the reason behind the request? Is this code ultimately intended for an environment where there are specified restrictions on the implementation, e.g. no floating point, no dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: I don't know what to do. My superior made himself clear that we were to utilize the linux system calls, and not to use `<stdio.h>`, as the software we create needs to work on our legacy systems. I wrote it how I knew how to write it, and looked up `write` and `read` and don't understand how to properly implement these. All I want is a program that takes text and reverses the output.

Comment: @AviBerger yes that is basically their reasoning. They need to be sure that I can use these tools properly before creating for the company properly.

Comment: @ikegami thank you so much, I will do my best to try and implement this!

Comment: So the request does make sense. You need to write code that will run on systems, unlike your own, where these routines are not available.

Comment: @Avi Berger, The request they made doesn't help achieve that.

Comment: @ikegami ): sorry, I wasn't sure how to properly state my question

Comment: Yup, I said as much, and that's fine, and it's why we asked for clarification about what you really wanted to do. This is called an [XY Problem](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341). I was going to add that to my initial comment, but it had become ineditable.

Answer (score 1):

> *don't understand how to properly implement [`read` and `write`]*

Assuming you mean call them (not implement them), the catch with `read` and `write` is that they may read or write less than requested, so you have to call them in a loop.

```
size_t to_write = strlen(str);
while (to_write) {
   ssize_t written = write(fd, str, to_write);
   if (written < 0) {
      perror(NULL);
      exit(1);
   }

   str      += written;
   to_write -= written;
}
```

Reading works the same way if you know how much you need to read or if you're trying to read an entire file. (To read the entire file, read chunks until `read` returns `0`. Factors of `8*1024` are nice chunk sizes.)

Otherwise, it gets far more complicated. How do you know how much to read before you read it? If you want to read a line, for example, you have no idea how long the line is until you encounter the terminating line feed. You could read a character at a time, but that's very inefficient. You could do like like stdio does and use a buffer that holds the excess. At which point you might as well use stdio.

Comment: I think I'm just reading whatever is in a `.txt` file for now

Answer (score 0):

```
//#include<stdio.h> not used
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
char* swap(const char *one, const char *two)
{
    char *result = malloc(strlen(one) + strlen(two) + 1);
    strcpy(result, one);
    strcat(result, two);
    return result;
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

if (argc != 2){
printf("Error, wrong number of arguments!\n");
exit(1);
}
    int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY); //<------------------<
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0; 
   char *string1 = "rev ";
   char *string2 = {argv[1]};
   char *result = swap(string1,string2);
   system(result); 

   return 0;
}
```